# In javascript, how to check listbox item (from html) from a listbox that may not exist

Tags: javascript, html

I was handed some code from a previous employee and need to make some updates, mainly pertaining to input validation.

**I am very much a novice at html and javascript.**

The form allows users to add rows by a button.  This button is really just creating another list box for users to select an additional item from.  Many rows can be added, but let's pretend it's limited to 3 list boxes for this question.  This is handled in the html code.

Based on another selection on the form though, some of the list box option will not be allowed, and I'd like to throw a message out if the user needs to change the form.

The problem comes from me verifying list box selections for a variable number of list boxes.  Here is some example code to help simplify what I'm trying to ask:

HTML:

(just the table portion here, the rest seems fine)

```
 <select name="type1" id="type1">
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option3</option>
 </select>
```

(The code for adding a row from the button click is here, but that seems to run fine as well.  New tables added are created in a javascript file and the name and type are incremented by 1 each time (type2, then type 3, etc).)

javascript:

```
function validate_form()
{
    //other options

    var Table1=document.getElementById("type1");  //This will always exist
    var Table2=document.getElementById("type2");  //This may not exist
    var Table3=document.getElementById("type3");  //This may not always exist

    //other code

    if (otherParameterFromForm == 'true')
    {
       if(Table1.options[2].selected)
       {
          alert("Invalid option for other Parameter selected.");
       }
       if(Table2.options[2].selected)  //if only 1 row, this causes script to stop`
       {
          alert("Invalid option for other Parameter selected.");
       }
       if(Table3.options[2].selected)  //if 2 or fewer rows, this causes script to stop
       {
          alert("Invalid option for other Parameter selected.");
       }
    }
```

}

So if the user has less than 3 list boxes, and I reference one that is not created, the script seems to just fail.  I have looked into checking to verify that the other list boxes exist (ie, typeof Table3 !== 'undefined') but nothing seems to work.  I also tried throwing out alerts for the various Tables and related values (quick-and-dirty debugging), but again, any reference to a list box Table variable that has not been created will cause the script to fail, even when trying to verify its existence.

So let's imagine the user only has 2 tables.  Anytime I do the check for Table3 (if it exist, or whatever) my script dies.

So for instance, assuming 2 tables created:

```
    var Table1=document.getElementById("type1");  //This will always exist
    var Table2=document.getElementById("type2");  //This may not exist
    var Table3=document.getElementById("type3");  //This may not  exist

    alert("Test1");
    if(systemNameTable3 === null){
       alert("test2");
    }
```

I will get the "Test1" alert, but not "Test2".

Is there a way to check if a table in HTML exist or not before assigning it to a variable?  Is there a way to use a variable that may not exist in this way in an if statement without making the script die (or reference it in any way that is won't)?  Is there a better way to go about this (without a complete overhaul of the code... that might be for another day).

Comment: is document.getElementById("option1") actually meant to be document.getElementById("type1") ?

Comment: @JonSG, Correct. Great catch! I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!document.getElementById("option1")) {
    alert("Option 1 does not exist");
if (!document.getElementById("option2")) {
    alert("Option 2 does not exist");
if (!document.getElementById("option3")) {
    alert("Option 3 does not exist");
```

Html :

```
<select name="type1" id="type1">
<option id="option1" value="option1">Option1</option>
<option id="option2" value="option2">Option2</option>
<option id="option3" value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Correcting for my typo (option1->type1, etc..), this solution worked for what I was trying to do.  While I'm sure the others do as well (I swore I tried some of them, but may have missed something), I am going to accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Table2=document.getElementById("option3");

if (Table2) { //meaning, if Table2 is NOT 'falsy'
//then do the following..
```

Answer (score 0):

@rsn answer not should have have been dismissed so quickly.  The "falsey" test on Table2 helps validate that we can work with it.

In the following code, I have provided a couple of ways to address the issue.  Method1 kind of mirrors what you are doing now.  Method2 does something similar, but in a more compact form.

```js
var Table1=document.getElementById("type1");  //This will always exist
var Table2=document.getElementById("type2");  //This may not exist
var Table3=document.getElementById("type3");  //This may not always exist

// ==================================
// are any of them set to option2?
// ==================================
if(Table1) {
    if("option2" === Table1.value) { alert("Method1 : This is not a valid choice."); }
}

if(Table2) {
    if("option2" === Table2.value) { alert("Method1 : This is not a valid choice."); }
}

if(Table3) {
    if("option2" === Table3.value) { alert("Method1 : This is not a valid choice."); }
}
// ==================================


// ==================================
// I might do this though for mostly the same effect
// ==================================
var myTables = document.querySelectorAll("select");
for (var i=0; i < myTables.length; i++) {
    if(myTables[i] && "option2" === myTables[i].value) { alert("Method2 : Invalid choice found."); }
}
// ==================================
```

```html
<select name="type1" id="type1">
  <option value="option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="option2" selected="selected">Option2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>

<select name="type2" id="type2">
  <option value="option1">Option1</option>
</select>
```